# refresh component on edit and add row

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I have a parent component AdsbyuserComponent, i need to edit or add a row using ag-grid.
i've managed to send informations to server but on closing the popup form, i couldn't refresh the table.
here's my code

AdsbyuserComponent

```
  update(ad :Ad) {
    let ngbModalOptions: NgbModalOptions = {
       backdrop : 'static',
       keyboard : false ,
   };
   const modalRef = this.modalService.open(EditAdComponent,ngbModalOptions);
   modalRef.componentInstance.ad = ad;
  }
```

EditAdComponent

```
onFormSubmitEdit() {
    this.activeModal.close();
    this.submitted = true;
    if (this.adForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }
    const ad = this.adForm.value;
    this.authService.getCurrentUser().subscribe((result) => {
      if (result) {
        ad.idowner = result.idUser;
        this.adService.updateAd(ad).subscribe(
          (res) => {
          },
          (err) => {
            console.log(err);
            alert(err.error);
          }
        );
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've managed to solve the problem using :

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/RefreshComponent', { skipLocationChange: true }).then(() => {
    this.router.navigate(['Your actualComponent']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reload page add this at the end of submit: `window.location.reload();` maybe thats can help

Comment: thank you for your reponse, i only need to refresh the parent component and not the whole page.

Comment: did you add <router-outlet></router-outlet>